# How to get Swagger to use @ApplicationPath?

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger

swagger-jaxrs 1.5.18

I have an Application at @ApplicationPath("/docs"), and under it a resource at @Path("/mydocs"). The real endpoint is thus /api/docs/mydocs, but what is generated in swagger.json is /api/mydocs.

Desired swagger url: /api/docs/mydocs

Actual swagger url: /api/mydocs

What is have to do to make it work is have `@ApplicationPath("")` in Applications and `@Path("/docs/mydocs")` in Resources, but I don't want to change all of our paths arbitrarily like that just to make it work with Swagger.

[There's a ticket on swagger's github that has been resolved, but for some reason it doesn't work for me (I am using what I think is the latest.)](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2489)

```
@ApplicationPath( "/docs" )
@Api( tags = "docs" )
public class DocsConfig extends Application {

    public DocsConfig() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion( "1.0" );
        beanConfig.setSchemes( new String[]{ "http" } );
        beanConfig.setHost( "localhost:8080" );
        beanConfig.setBasePath( "/api" );
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage( "com.my.company" );
        beanConfig.setScan( true );
        beanConfig.setTitle( "MY API" );

    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add( io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class );
        resources.add( io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class );
        resources.add( DocsResource.class );
        return resources;
    }
}

@Stateless
@Path( "/mydocs" )
@Api( value = "mydocs" )
public class DocsResource {

    @Context
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Path( "/ui" )
    @GET
    public InputStream getFile() {
        //some stuff
    }
}

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: My hunch tells me if you change `beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");` to `beanConfig.setBasePath("/api/docs");` it will work :)

Comment: The mentioned issue [#2489](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2489) is said to be fixed on the 2.0 branch only. As you are using 1.5.18 the support for `@ApplicationPath` will not be available.

Comment: On the "setBasePath("/api/docs")" fix, it looks like it works for the most part aside from prepending that to our other url's in the swagger.json output. This is because we have multiple Application classes with different ApplicationPath()'s in addition to docs. Example: ApplicationPath("/thing1"), /api/thing1 becomes /api/docs/thing1 in the swagger.json. We have it scanning the project for swagger annotations (which we thought was correct, but we might have set it up incorrectly). I assume the complete workaround would be to set that in every Application class we have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the support for `@ApplicationPath` has been added in Swagger 2.0 only. With Swagger 1.5 you have the option to either include the application path in your swagger config's base path (as mentioned by @imTachu):

```
final String applicationPath = DocsConfig.class.getAnnotation(ApplicationPath.class).value();
beanConfig.setBasePath("/api" + applicationPath);
```

This will result in the generated YAML to look like this:

```
...
basePath: "/api/docs"
...
paths:
  /mydocs/ui:
...
```

Or you can write a `ReaderListener` that modifies the generated Swagger as needed:

```
@SwaggerDefinition
public class SwaggerBasePathModifier implements ReaderListener {

  @Override
  public void beforeScan(Reader aReader, Swagger aSwagger) {
    // do nothing
  }

  @Override
  public void afterScan(Reader aReader, Swagger aSwagger) {
    final Map<String, Path> newSwaggerPaths = new HashMap<>();
    final String applicationPath = DocsConfig.class.getAnnotation(ApplicationPath.class).value();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Path> entry : aSwagger.getPaths().entrySet()) {
      final currKey = entry.getKey().substring("/api".length(), entry.getKey().length())
      final String newKey = "/api" + applicationPath + currKey;
      newSwaggerPaths.put(newKey, entry.getValue());
    }
    aSwagger.setPaths(newSwaggerPaths);
  }
}
```

This will result in each path in the generated YAML to be modified. That is you get:

```
...
basePath: "/api"
...
paths:
  /docs/mydocs/ui:
...
```

By using the first option all requests will use the same base path `/api/docs`, while the latter option allows you to configure multiple base paths (e.g. for multiple JAX-RS servers configured in the same application) and is more flexible.

Comment: Is there a jaxrs version of swagger 2.0? I'd like to use the latest if I can. I see the up to 1.5.18 on Jan 2018, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. I will try the methods you two gave for now, thank you.

Comment: There is swagger-jaxrs2. As swagger 2 has not yet been released the guides may still be subject to change: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-2.0.X